# How can I set/get tag value (NSInteger) for UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have dynamic `UISwitches` that I create using the for loop. I give the tag value for each control to have an identity. I want to reach these values ​​later, but I get 0 each time. What I'm doing wrong?

```
for(int i = 0;i < self.extraArray.count; i++) {

    ProductPropertiesModel *model = (ProductPropertiesModel *)[self.extraArray objectAtIndex:i];

    UISwitch *switchButton = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];    
    switchButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;    
    switchButton.tag = [model Id];    
    [switchButton setOn:NO];    
    [self.view addSubview:switchButton];    
    [switchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

-(void)setState:(id)sender
{

    UISwitch *uiswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;    
    NSInteger tagInteger= uiswitch.tag;    
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)tagInteger]);

}
```

The tag value is 0, but that is wrong.

Comment: I would put two breakpoints. One to verify that the `tag` is set correctly (there could be an issue with `[model Id]` for example) and a second to verify that sender is what I expect it to be. As a sidenote, `- (void)setState:(UISwitch *)sender` could be a more appropriate signature in your case, in order to avoid subsequent casting, provided that it would only be used with `UISwitch`es.

Comment: Thank you Alladinian, I found the problem. I just made a typo. I noticed that I was writing a typo when I was taking json data. I noticed Id writing instead of id. NSInteger *Id = (NSInteger *)[(NSNumber *)[[self.extraJsonArray objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend instead setting `[model id]` as tag, you should set array index as tag.

and then later on in the switch control method, you can get the value from array index, using the code.

```
  ProductPropertiesModel *model = (ProductPropertiesModel *)[self.extraArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Surbhi, I found the problem. I just made a typo. I noticed that I was writing a typo when I was taking json data. I noticed Id writing instead of id. NSInteger *Id = (NSInteger *)[(NSNumber *)[[self.extraJsonArray objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I just made a typo. I noticed that I was writing a typo when I was taking json data. I noticed Id writing instead of id.

```
NSError *jsonError;
        self.extraJsonArray = nil;
        self.extraJsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
        self.extraArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(int j = 0;j < self.extraJsonArray.count;j++){
            @try {
                //NSInteger *Id = (NSInteger *)[(NSNumber *)[[self.extraJsonArray objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"Id"] integerValue]; Problem is here
                NSInteger *Id = (NSInteger *)[(NSNumber *)[[self.extraJsonArray objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
                double price = (double)[(NSNumber *)[[self.extraJsonArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"price"] doubleValue];
                NSString *property =(NSString *)[[self.extraJsonArray objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"property"];
                ProductPropertiesModel *model = [[ProductPropertiesModel alloc] init];
                [model setId:Id];
                [model setProperty:property];
                [model setPrice:price]; 
                [model setChecked:@"No"];
                [self.extraArray addObject:model];
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"%@", exception.reason);
            } @finally {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i =0; i < self.extraArray.count; i++) {

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, height, width);
    UISwitch *switchControl = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    //add tag as index 
    switchControl.tag = i;
    [switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [switchControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:switchControl];

    y= y+50.0;
}

- (IBAction) setState: (UISwitch *) sender {    
    NSLog(@"no.%d %@",sender.tag, sender.on ? @"On" : @"Off");
    //use sender.tag , you know which switch you selected 
}
```